# How are neutrinos massless? Could they or at least some of their forms be a potential candidate for Dark matter?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, mass, dark-matter, neutrinos

I am particularly new to this subject. Can neutrino physics be understood by a 10th grade?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17227/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158319/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15320/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Abhik. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please only ask 1 question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Neutrinos were long believed to be massless, but they actually are not. Now we know that there are three discrete neutrino masses (they are *tiny*). There are three different neutrino flavors, and each specific flavor has a quantum superposition of the three mass states. More on neutrinos [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino).

Yes, a 10th grader can learn neutrino physics, if diligent enough! I'm currently an 11th grader, and started learning particle physics in 8th grade. There is a free course from the University of Geneva on an [Introduction to Particle Physics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/particle-physics#about). The course requires some prior knowledge of classical physics and special relativity. But it is certainly learn-able. Another resource I would have you check out is [MIT's Open CourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm), where you can find free lectures and lecture notes on practically any topic.