# Why can't Dark matter be made up mostly of Neutrinos?

Tags: cosmology, universe, neutrinos, dark-matter

It's said that Neutirnos can only make up a tiny fraciton of dark matter.
So why can't Dark matter be mostly made up of Neutrinos?
Why can't there just be a huge number of them?
I suspect myself that neutrinos are so light that they end up being "too fast". But I'm not sure myself.

Comment: Possible duplicates https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17227/  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158319/  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560562/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we know Dark Matter isn't simply Neutrinos?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17227/)

Comment: Based on the properties of neutrinos, observations reveal how many of them are passing through any region of space. The possible exception is a sterile neutrino which we won't be able to observe so easily.