# How did neutrinos eliminated from dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, universe, neutrinos, dark-matter, cosmic-microwave-background

I am reading "[Dark Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) and [Dark Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy)" by [Brian Clegg](https://www.brianclegg.net/dmde.html).

In Chapter 3 it's discussing about [cosmic microwave background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) and the elliptical shape
of early universe obtained from it and then concluded that

> "This data enabled cosmologists to eliminate neutrinos as the source
> of dark matter."

How did it reach to this conclusion?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17227/2451

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is technical and has to do with structure formation. The term to look for is "[hot dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_dark_matter)", so-called because hot particles move quickly.

> In terms of its application, the distribution of hot dark matter could also help explain how clusters and superclusters of galaxies formed after the Big Bang. Theorists claim that there exist two classes of dark matter: 1) those that "congregate around individual members of a cluster of visible galaxies" and 2) those that encompass "the clusters as a whole." Because cold dark matter possesses a lower velocity, it could be the source of "smaller, galaxy-sized lumps," as shown in the image. **Hot dark matter, then, should correspond to the formation of larger mass aggregates that surround whole galaxy clusters. However, data from the cosmic microwave background radiation, as measured by the COBE satellite, is highly uniform, and such high-velocity hot dark matter particles cannot form clumps as small as galaxies beginning from such a smooth initial state**, highlighting a discrepancy in what dark matter theory and the actual data are saying. Theoretically, in order to explain relatively small-scale structures in the observable Universe, it is necessary to invoke cold dark matter or WDM. In other words, hot dark matter being the sole substance in explaining cosmic galaxy formation is no longer viable, placing hot dark matter under the larger umbrella of mixed dark matter (MDM) theory.