# What is dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter

My friend asked me about [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) and started saying that it is likely to be another world made up of things we say dark matter and energy said that quantum fluctuations may be the cause of dark matter although I didn't believe what you says?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+is+Dark+matter

Comment: It's a lot of things, but it's not "another world". Whatever it may be, another quantum field (or several), or a modification of Newtonian gravity, it is very much "of this world". We can fairly confidently say that without dark matter there would not be enough gravitation to form galaxies in the early universe. "This world" would be a giant, rapidly expanding gas cloud. I reserve the right to ignore direct collapse models at this time, since they are not confirmed and I don't know if they are possible without dark matter, either.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1008/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17227/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The Wikipedia article (the link added by Qmechanic) says nothing about other worlds or quantum fluctuations. Dark matter is just some kind of matter that’s dark.